Does a relation on the matrix determinant always exist for subgroup equivalent classes
Let  $H$  be a subgroup of the group $\{ A\in M_{n \times n} : \left| A \right|\neq 0 \}$
Two matrices are said to be equivalent mod $H$ if $AB^{-1}\in H$
For every $H$, is there an equivalence relation $\mathfrak{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all invertible $A, B$ $AB^{-1} \in H \Longleftrightarrow  \det A \underset{\mathfrak{R}}{\equiv}  \det B   $?
For instance, if $H = \{ A\in M_{n \times n} : \left| A \right| = 1 \} $, then $\mathfrak{R}$  is just normal equality. if $H = \{ A\in M_{n \times n} : \left| A \right| = a^{n} ,n \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$, then it is $mod\space a$ equivalence over $\log_{a}{\det} $ of the matrices. Is this a general principle? I couldn't come up with a counter-example, nor a proof.

Trivially, the relation with $a \equiv b$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$ should work.

@Tzimmo I'm not sure what you mean.. Can you elaborate? If I understood correctly, this wouldn't work in the case $ \det A = a^{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

typo: $ n \in \mathbb{Z} $

It does work. The right side of the implication is always true, so the implication is fulfilled. Are you maybe looking for an equivalence instead of an implication?

Oh yes, that was a typo.. I will update and add an elaboration.

I'm not sure if this is equivalent: Is there a 1-1 homeomorphism between the cosets of $H$ and the equivalence classes of some $ \mathfrak{R}$ defined on the determinant?

Your question amonts to the following problem: Is every subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ the preimage of a subgroup of $\mathbb R^\times$ under the determinant?
The answer is no. Consider the subgroup of diagonal matrices $H = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} : a,b \neq 0\right\} \leq \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ or even the trivial subgroup $H = \{I\}$. Here, $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Then $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is not contained in $H$, so $A \cdot I^{-1} \notin H$. Both $A$ and $I$, however, have the same determinant $1$, so necessarily have $\operatorname{det} A \equiv \operatorname{det} I$ for any equivalence relation.
